# Gson force field to be string

Tags: android, gson

I have a class where i have a field named "list_elements" as String.
This is a jsonObject in my HttpResponse, so gson serialization want parse it to OBject instead of as String.

I can i force Gson to parse this as String ?

Thank's

Comment: Can you include your JSON as well as your Java .class that are going for serialization?

Comment: Did you really try that? In my experience, Gson looks at the field's type and tries its best to convert the value from the JSON into that type ... and I guess, they are able to convert a JSON object into a string.

Comment: Yes i d'ont understand why it try to parse my object instead of set string

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own deserializers. Here is an example:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;

public class MyModelDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyModel> {
    @Override
    public MyModel deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject aJson = json.getAsJsonObject();
        String myStringObject = aJson.get("myJsonObjectKeyWhichIwantToParseLikeString").getAsJsonObject().toSttring()
        MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
        myModel.setMyStringObject(myStringObject);
        //Dont forget to deserialize and set in myModel another fields from json if needed.
        return myModel;
    }
}
```

and don't forget to register your deserializer in gson builder. You can do this in that way:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            ...
            .registerTypeAdapter(MyModel.class, new MyModelDeserializer())
            .create()
```

Comment: I would not use this solution because, i would to automatically map my json to object without write Serializer.

Comment: So then I suggest you you to write a annotation which will transform your field and process it in compile time by annotation processor or runtime by reflection. Is the easiest way to keep the model simple :)